# What did Sommerfeld mean by Bohr's magic wand?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

### Background

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle):

"Bohr's correspondence principle demands that classical physics and quantum physics give the same answer when the systems become large.[5] A. Sommerfeld (1924) referred to the principle as "Bohrs Zauberstab" (Bohr's magic wand)."

### Question

Does A. Sommerfeld make a hidden pee pee joke over here? From the context and translation of this German I feel this is likely; since it's used in the context of taking the limit of a system to "large".

I would like to know if this joke would make sense in German? Is there any evidence to further strengthen my case? Or am I reading too much "in between the lines"?

Comment: I'm a native German speaker and I don't see a "pee pee joke" here, or any joke for that matter. Also, I'm not sure if this site is the right place for this question.

Comment: Hmmm .. to be fair I don't make as strong a case as I could due to vulgarity ... can you post an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“*A cigar is sometimes just a cigar*”, Freud. The original appearance is in 1919's edition of [*Atombau und Spektrallinien*](https://archive.org/details/atombauundspekt00sommgoog/page/n10), not Wikipedia's 1924's, long before the "new" quantum mechanics. Bohr did wield his  *Zauberstab* to import classical results into quantum physics, despite the inconsistency between the two, and to match the right answers from the spectral measurements. The context is discussed in [Borelli's The emergence of selection rules and their encounter with group theory, 1913-1927](http://www.weatherglass.eu/PDFs/selectionRulesSubmittedPDF.pdf):

> "*Using classical electromagnetism, Rubinowicz computed the angular momentum of a
>   spherical wave and showed that, when renormalized by $h/2π$, it had an absolute value equal or less than one. (Rubinowicz, 1918a, pp. 443-444). This led to a selection principle for the azimuthal
>   quantum number: $\Delta n = 0, ±1$ (Rubinowicz, 1918a, pp. 444-445)... It was left to Sommerfeld, in the first edition of Atombau und Spektrallinien (1919), to connect Bohr and Rubinowicz's results to his own interpretation of spectral terms as linked to
>   azimuthal quantum numbers. Sommerfeld showed a very clear preference for the theory of his
>   former assistant Rubinowicz, which he discussed at length (Sommerfeld, 1919, pp. 390-411).*
>
> *Rubinowicz's "selection principle" was for Sommerfeld a means to bridge the gap between classical and quantum physics... He admitted that Bohr's condition $\Delta n = ±1$ fitted much better
>   the Rydberg-Ritz formula than Rubinowicz's, but made clear the epistemological gap he perceived
>   between a theoretically significant selection principle like Rubinowicz's, on the one side, and Bohr's
>   empirically successful condition, on the other. The latter, he described as a "magic wand"
>   ("Zauberstab") to make quantum theory useful in practice (Sommerfeld, 1919, pp. 406-411, quote
>   from p. 402)*".